# JSON Post PHP (TypeForm)

Tags: php, json, typeform

I have never used JSON before so apologies if this is a simple request.

I have a webhook setup that sends me a JSON Post (Example Below) - I want to extract the two answers from this `"text":"250252"` & `{"label":"CE"}`

```
{
  "event_id": "1",
  "event_type": "form_response",
  "form_response": {
    "form_id": "VpWTMQ",
    "token": "1",
    "submitted_at": "2018-05-22T14:11:56Z",
    "definition": {
      "id": "VpWTMQ",
      "title": "SS - Skill Change",
      "fields": [
        {
          "id": "kUbaN0JdLDz8",
          "title": "Please enter your ID",
          "type": "short_text",
          "ref": "9ac66945-899b-448d-859f-70562310ee5d",
          "allow_multiple_selections": false,
          "allow_other_choice": false
        },
        {
          "id": "JQD4ksDpjlln",
          "title": "Please select the skill required",
          "type": "multiple_choice",
          "ref": "a24e6b58-f388-4ea9-9853-75f69e5ca337",
          "allow_multiple_selections": false,
          "allow_other_choice": false
        }
      ]
    },
    "answers": [
      {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "250252",
        "field": {
          "id": "kUbaN0JdLDz8",
          "type": "short_text"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "choice",
        "choice": {
          "label": "CE"
        },
        "field": {
          "id": "JQD4ksDpjlln",
          "type": "multiple_choice"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have this currently in my PHP file:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$ID = $data->{"text"};
$Skill = $data->{"label"};
```

This does not work and all I get is null - Any help would really be appreciated, Thank You.

Comment: can you `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the JSON object you're receiving to know the structure of the object you're receiving after using `json_decode`, what you're trying to get is in `$data->form_response->answers`, So you can have a variable for easier access:

```
$answers = $data->form_response->answers;
```

remember `$answers` is an array

So to achieve what you're trying to get, you can do:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$answers = $data->form_response->answers;
$ID = $answers[0]->text;
$Skill = $answers[1]->choice->label;
```