# Reading JSON from HTTP POST using PHP (Typeform)

Tags: php, json, typeform

I'm having trouble reading JSON data (using PHP) that's coming in from a webhook (Typeform.)

I've tried the solution provided [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50472952/json-post-php-typeform?newreg=398b1765fceb4917b4c5eee085d2f108) but I'm still getting a null array. My code is exactly the same as the example shown in the link (although I'm not accessing particular arrays, I just want to read the data.) All my test deliveries are returning 200, so I'm just a bit stuck.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeForm runs the page, They'll get the var_dump response...

When you run the page, you haven't posted anything so $data is empty, therefore null

Try saving $data to a file, then when TypeForm POSTS to it, You can see what the POST contents were, in that file

```
file_put_contents("webhookData.txt",$data, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I added the code you mentioned underneath the file_get_contents line, and although I still get a 200 code back from Typeform, there's nothing being written to the txt file. I can see the payload from Typeform's test delivery though so that should be written to the txt file correct?

Comment: Yes, the text file should contain everything that Typeform has sent to the server.. Technically speaking if Typeform is POSTing JSON data, you could just put $_POST as the file data source instead of $data.  Try that and see what data you're getting

Comment: I replaced $data with $_POST and the txt file is still empty after test deliveries and a form submission.

Comment: Are you sure the page is getting hits? double check that the file is getting data from the Typeform side

Comment: The url for the webhook is correct (the tests have returned 200, and the form submissions as well) but in chrome dev, there is no network activity upon submission of a test delivery or form submission.

Comment: I understand my response is getting sent back to Typeform, I'm just not understanding why the request data won't write to the txt file as you suggested. I can't persist Typeform's request to a SESSION variable as it triggers a 500 error when I run the page. It feels like a pretty minor error that I'm just ignorant of, so any help is so greatly appreciated :)

Comment: When you added a session variable it quit working? Ohhhhhhhhh. 2 things. 1. Make sure the first thing in the code is session_start(); and make sure the permissions on the html folder (root public directory, where the script is) is set to 775. It's possible it's trying to write but it can't because it doesn't have permissions

Comment: If none of that helps, we could do a screen share session and I could have a look at it

Comment: I had session_start(); at the top before using the session variable, but somehow managed to mess up the permissions for my 'home' directory in winscp so I'm trying to figure that out. Thank you for your quick response!

Comment: I tried changing public_html to 775, but the pages in question produced a 500 error when trying to pull them up. How much do you charge?